# How do I get logs when Mesos agent launch task failed

Tags: mesos

I tried to write a self-defined scheduler(use HTTP API), Mesos master accept my task launch, but mesos agent raise a TASK_FAILED status update. I want to know where I can get more detailed logs about why task is failed.
My Mesos is 1.6.0, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places to look:

1. Check a task [status update message](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/903854890b86288fab88b77c6264ea6e2abb17ee/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L1880) and [a reason](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/903854890b86288fab88b77c6264ea6e2abb17ee/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L1882)
2. Take a look at Mesos sandbox and examine stdout/stderr and other logs generated by your app. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44059751/1387612) you have instruction how to do it.

You may need to decipher the problem from exit code. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803610/where-to-find-more-explicit-errors-given-container-error-status-codes/43819594#43819594) is an expalantaion how to do it.